# How to insert a button with an onclick attribute into a web page using IE via AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to insert a button into a div on a page using IE and AHK.  The button insertion I can do, but how do I get the onclick to work

This is what I have:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

wb := IEGet("Page1")

inp := wb.document.createElement("input")

typ := wb.document.createAttribute("type")
typ.value := "button"

val := wb.document.createAttribute("value")
val.value := "Click Me!"

btnclick := wb.document.createAttribute("onclick")
btnclick.value := "alert(123)"

inp.setAttributeNode(typ)
inp.setAttributeNode(val)
inp.setAttributeNode(btnclick)

wb.document.all.external.appendChild(inp)



IEGet(Name="")        ;Retrieve pointer to existing IE window/tab
{
    IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame
    {
        Name := ( Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer" ) ? "about:Tabs" : RegExReplace( Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft) Internet Explorer" )
    }

    For wb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
    {
        If ( wb.LocationName = Name ) && InStr( wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
        {
            Return wb
        }
    }
}
```

The div has an id of "external".  I'm using IE 11, Win 8.1 and AHK 1.1.19.01.  The page title is "Page1".

When I run the above script, I get the button. I inspect it and it looks like this:

```
<input onclick="alert(123)" type="button" value="Click Me!">
```

How do I get the button to actually fire the dynamically created onclick attribute when I click it?  It's as if IE won't recognize it as an event to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trigger the click event using the `.Click()` method.

**Example usage:**

```
wb.document.getElementsById("ExampleButton").Click()
```

Read more about the Click method (MDN):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Comment: Sorry - I didn't make myself clear.  I don't want to auto click it, I just want the click event to work when I click it with the mouse.

Comment: hmmm... your code are actually works... except for the "type". when i click it, i see the message box with "123"....

Comment: Hi Joe - what version of IE, windows, and ahk are you using?

Comment: IE11 and AHK v1.1.19.02

Comment: and are you using win 8.1?

Comment: No, I'm using Win7 x64

Comment: Hmm... Try it With "try-catch" blocks?